# Is constraining template parameters bad practice?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

In C++, it is legal to assume a template parameter has certain fields or methods according to [this source](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#constraints). In case it does not, it will simply fail to compile.

```
template<class Container>
void draw_all(Container& c)
{
    for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),mem_fun(&Shape::draw));
}
```

In this example, `Container` has to implement `begin()` and `end()` in order for the program to compile. However, looking at the prototype of the function, no such restriction seems apparent.

In other words, the information on the usage of the interface becomes intertwined with the implementation (even when using `static_assert`).

This to me seems like bad practice (although I myself encountered situations where it still was the most elegant solution I could find). Is it, or if not, what would be the justification for using this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: You're probably inadvertendly misusing the term, but you do the opposite of what you asking. Your template parameter is currently not constrained, and you're asking how to constrain it.

Comment: Before C++20, it was not easy to constraint template, and even with constraint, there are no checks that only "allowed" functions are used.

Comment: @Vivick: I meant, it is a language choice to allow it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think your comment highlights the core of my question. My template parameter is not constrained in the sense that nothing in the interface (the function template prototype) indicates that the template can't be instantiated. It is however constrained in the sense that it won't work with just any type. This is apparent only when peeking at the implementation, which to me seems to contradict static typing in some sense. I'm not necessarily asking how to show this constraint in the interface, just whether using this construct is bad practice, or if it can be justified.

Comment: Look up the concept of being "SFINAE-friendly". It's usually ok, but adding requirements to the interface will let other code  programmatically check if your function can be called on their type before actually attempting it and maybe getting a compilation error.

Comment: A shame this got closed, could write an answer that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until C++20, this is all we had. The one thing you cannot take away from C++ templates pre C++20 is that they allowed for great flexibility (which can be needed in some cases), and in a way allowed for an implicit contract between the API provider and the API consumer.

C++20 came along and introduced [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) almost literally to fix the issues caused by how loose said contracts were.

Nowadays, that function would likely be written as:

```
template <class Container>
concept DrawableContainer = requires (Container c) {
  { c.begin() };
  { c.end() };
  { *(c.begin()) } -> std::convertible_to<typename Container::value_type>;
  requires std::invocable<decltype(&Shape::draw), decltype(*(c.begin()))>;
  // Plus whatever else constraints are needed
};

void draw_all(DrawableContainer auto& c)
{
    for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),mem_fun(&Shape::draw));
}
```

This still allows the same flexibility, but has the added feature of being better documented even with just code.

If you don't have access to concepts, there's no better solution than a good old template. You can try to use SFINAE everywhere to make it a bit easier to use.

Comment: You add restriction... `Container::value_type` is not needed in OP  code.

Comment: It's an example

Comment: Pre-C++20 we had `enable_if` and the conventional SFINAE.

Comment: Cf. Last paragraph